# Why is req.ip in node/Express returning colon separated IP addresses?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to log the remote client IP. Sounds elementary and Express provides the "ip" property on the request object, as in req.ip, to get this info. Also, there is req.ips to get multiple IP addresses from X-Forwarded-For where proxies are involved. I also tried the npm module [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip)-ip. My question is that they all return client IP addresses as in

```
 ::ffff:A.B.C.D
```

where A.B.C.D is indeed the address I am looking for. But, my question is: what are the prefixes there? I can understand req.ips or X-Forwarded-For returning multiple IP addresses but even there I would expect real IP addresses not nulls.

Of course I can get the last address but I want to know what the colon-separated blank entries mean even when trying to get just the single req.ip address?

Comment: It looks like you're getting an IPv6 address, that's all.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo  Thats it! If you post this as an answer I will accept it. I guess there must be someway to get if in a IPv4 format but more importantly I wanted to know what the output was and you answered that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double colon `::` is a shortcut in IPv6 to indicate a string of zeros as spoken of in [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/444554/what-does-mean-as-an-ip-address-bracket-colon-colon-bracket). The first part `::fff:` is a prefix for IPv4 address that are embedded in an IPv6 address as part of [the transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Transition_from_IPv4) to IPv6.

```
::ffff:A.B.C.D
--v6-- --v4--
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer. If Edwin Dalorzo does not post an answer, I will accept yours as an answer. He posted the answer first, although as a comment.