# req.ip returning colon separated values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ip-address, cloudflare

**Desired Behaviour**

Get the user's IP address via `req.ip` in a Node/MongoDB/Azure environment that has Cloudflare enabled and `app.set('trust proxy', true)` set.  You can see [the node docs on this setting here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html).

**Actual Behaviour**

The behaviour is not consistent, sometimes `req.ip` will return the desired value, eg 4 values separated by dots:

```
123.456.789.10
```

And sometimes it returns values like this, eg 8 values separated by colons:

```
2001:5005:1802:3500:18d2:k446:123b:g5h4
```

*values above are demonstrative only*

Additionally, I am capturing IP from two locations, firstly from `req.ip` server-side and secondly from an ajax request to [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io) client-side.  I use `req.ip` in case the `ipinfo.io` lookup fails.

So what is occurring in some cases, is that `ipinfo.io` will return a value in the expected format, whilst `req.ip` will return a different value in the unexpected format.  I would like these values to be consistent / the same.

**What I've Tried / Context**

The reason I am using `app.set('trust proxy', true)` in my node.js server file is because the site has Cloudflare enabled on it and I need to get the user's actual IP address.  I am using two rate limiter packages that apply limitations based on IP address and time - eg user1 can submit 3 requests every 5 minutes.  Therefore the IP address needs to be the actual requester, not the cloudflare proxy.

The packages used are:

[Express Rate Limit](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit) - the rate limiter logic
[Rate Limit Mongo](https://github.com/2do2go/rate-limit-mongo) - a supporting package that keeps track of requests from IP addresses in MongoDB

I've google searched for things like `req.ip returning string with colons node.js`, but results seems to relate to `double colons`, not `single colons`, eg:

[Why is req.ip in node/Express returning colon separated IP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120858/why-is-req-ip-in-node-express-returning-colon-separated-ip-addresses)

So they doesn't *seem* related.

I also googled `ip address formats` and came across this:

[IPv4 and IPv6 address formats](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STCMML8/com.ibm.storage.ts3500.doc/opg_3584_IPv4_IPv6_addresses.html)

Which seems to communicate that what I am seeing is an IPv6 address.

**Questions**

Why are the values returned from `ipinfo.io` (browser) and `req.ip` (server) different for the same user?

Why does `req.ip` return an `IPv4` address for some users and an `IPv6` address for other users?

Should I, or can I, make `req.ip` return consistently formatted values, preferably the IPv4 format because it is easier to read and then my rate limiter mongodb entries will look consistent?

Answer (score 2):

Both ipv4 and ipv6 are 'correct' IP addresses. It's just different people connecting to your service in different protocols. You can choose to only support one of them, but it's a good idea to have support for both.

Your application will be more portable and usable for people if it supports both formats.